# ML-Agents Error while installing: pip3 install -e ./ml-agents-envs

Tags: unity-game-engine, installation, artificial-intelligence, game-development

i was making a new project for a ppo ai that i wanted to do so i was setting it up and installing all the things in anaconda, then it came up with this error while installing the: pip3 install -e ./ml-agents-envs
pip3 install -e ./ml-agents-envs
ERROR: ./ml-agents-envs is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh, bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+http, svn+https, svn+svn, svn+file).

i tried looking for anyone else that had this error too but i couldent find any posts about it. i was also able to install: pip3 install torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html. correcly so its not a pip thing like it was last time i had a problem installing things.
does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Where did you get that command from? Because as you see it is not really valid.

Comment: do you mean the error?

Comment: ohh sorry cant read rn apparently i got the command from the installation guide at https://unity-technologies.github.io/ml-agents/Installation/ 
at the bottom Advanced: Local Installation for Development section

Comment: That's the advanced one, not meant for you, the right command is before that: python -m pip install mlagents==0.30.0

Comment: so all i have to do next time is make a project add the ml agents package, make a virtual environment, navigate to the environment and the project file then put in that command right?